# How to fix Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject' to expected argument type '_?' error?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have this code that needs to sort items but unfortunately, I had encountered error `Cannot convert the value of type 'AnyObject' to expected argument type '_?'`. As I tried to click the suggested solution, It says I need to input on the `_` but I don't know what will I insert. Please help me solve this issue. I was looking for a solution here in StackOverflow but some solution is not applicable to my issue. Hope you could help me. Thank you

[image: error]

```
func sortItem(_ data1: Any?, _ data2: Any?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {
    let item1 = data1 as? NSMetadataItem
    let item2 = data2 as? NSMetadataItem

    let string1 = (item1?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as AnyObject)
    let string2 = (item2?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as AnyObject)

    return (string1?.compare(string2 ?? ""))
}
```

Comment: its a type mismatch error, just typecast strings as `String` instead `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a cast to String and you also need to have some logic that defines what is returned if the cast fails, here is an example

```
func sortItem(_ data1: Any?, _ data2: Any?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {
    let item1 = data1 as? NSMetadataItem
    let item2 = data2 as? NSMetadataItem

    guard let string1 = item1?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedAscending
    }
    guard let string2 = item2?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedDescending
    }

    return string1.compare(string2)
}
```

Since you are always casting your input parameters then why not rewrite the function as

```
func sortItem(_ data1: NSMetadataItem?, _ data2: NSMetadataItem?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {

    guard let item1 = data1, let string1 = item1.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedAscending
    }
    guard let item2 = data2, let string2 = item2.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedDescending
    }

    return string1.compare(string2)
}
```

Of course you don't have to write the code as dense as I have done here and have several `guard` statements or `if/else` depending on what logic you want to implement for nil values and values that are not strings

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast string1 into `String` not `AnyObject`

```
 func sortItem(_ data1: Any?, _ data2: Any?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {
        let item1 = data1 as? NSMetadataItem
        let item2 = data2 as? NSMetadataItem

        let string1 = (item1?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as! String)
        let string2 = (item2?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as! String)

        return (string1?.compare(string2 ?? ""))
    }
```